# Passing on data to Ionic modal created by a service

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am using the following [solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-modal-service-with-extras/15357) to create a Ionic Modal service, but at the moment, I am finding it difficult to pass in a into my modal. What can I do to rectify this:

**controller.js**

```
$scope.confirmBookingModal = function(val) {
  console.log(val);
  ModalService.show('templates/modals/confirm-booking.html', 'ConsumerBusinessProfileCtrl as vm', val);
}
```

**modal**

```
<ion-modal-view ng-controller="ConsumerBusinessProfileCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Confirm</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader bar-dark modal-padding">
    <h1 class="title">{{ vm.val }} services booked at £110 for 2 hours</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>


  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>

</ion-modal-view>
```

`val` outputs a value into the console, so there is some data in there, but I am not sure whether I am accessing it the correct way from the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
$scope.confirmBookingModal = function() {
  var vm = $scope;
  ModalService.show('templates/modals/confirm-booking.html', 'ConsumerBusinessProfileCtrl as vm');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already specifying your controller in your `.show()` method call, you don't need it in the modal template. Change the modal template as:

```
<ion-modal-view>

  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Confirm</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader bar-dark modal-padding">
    <h1 class="title">{{ vm.val }} services booked at £110 for 2 hours</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>


   <ion-content>
   </ion-content>

</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr for this?